# collecting mysql query result from table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to query a table in an associative array using singleton database connection and im getting error,

Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOBCASHIER\resources\templates\loginmodel.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOBCASHIER\resources\templates\loginmodel.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: loc in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOBCASHIER\resources\templates\loginmodel.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 3 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOBCASHIER\resources\templates\loginmodel.php on line 10

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOBCASHIER\resources\templates\loginmodel.php on line 12
Array

my db.config.php

```
define ('HOST','localhost');
define ('USER','garodamas_mon');
define ('PASSWORD','r0d4m45');
define ('DATABASE','garodamas_cashrcv');

class Database{
    private $DBH;
    private static $singleton;
    protected function __construct(){
        $this->DBH=new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
    }
    public static function instance(){
        if (!(self::$singleton instanceof self)) {
            self::$singleton = new self();
        }
        return self::$singleton;
    }
    public static function get(){
        return self::instance()->DBH;
    }
    private function __wake(){}
    private function __clone(){}
}
```

and my loginmodel.php

```
<?php
require_once '../db.config.php';


$get=Database::get()->prepare('SELECT user_id, user_name, user_dept FROM mst_user');
$get->execute();
$row = array();

$get->fetch($id, $name, $loc);
        while($get->fetch()){
            print($row);
        }
```

i dont know where my error is. mst_user has 3 columns. Please help me.. thanks

Comment: `SHOW *` create problem it would be `SELECT *`

Answer (score 1):

The [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-returnvalues) statement is returning false, because there is an error.

> mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

Try

```
new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE)->prepare('badsql')->execute();
```

And then fix the `badsql`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 require_once '../db.config.php';

$get=Database::get()->prepare('SELECT user_id, user_name, user_dept FROM mst_user');
$get->execute();
```

> with PDO:

```
while ($row = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        $data = $row[0] . "\t" . $row[1] . "\t" . $row[2] . "\n";
        print $data;
       }
```

> With Mysqli:

```
$get->bind_result($id,$name,$loc);
 while ($get->fetch()) {
        print ($id, $name, $code);
    }
```

Comment: im using mysqli not PDO

Comment: @KonzMama, I edited my answer, i think you forgot to bind result variables in Mysqli